# C++ - I have allocated a char array and the content is `�b

Tags: c++, char

I want to concatenate two const char* but when I do this I got these symbols: `�b

I do the following:

```
 char* path = new char[strlen(args->targetFileName) + strlen(args->targetFilePath)];
cout << path << endl;
strcat(path,args->targetFilePath);
cout << path << endl;
strcat(path,args->targetFileName);
cout << path << endl;
```

Output:

```
`�b
`�b/home/user/Arbeitsfläche/
`�b/home/user/Arbeitsfläche/Auto.png
```

Whats the fault?? Any suggestions??

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string`s?

Comment: Looks like a unicode issue..?

Comment: Nah, there's just junk in the cstring to begin with because it's not initialised.

Comment: Because of issue see Chris Parton & PlasmaHH.  Unmanaged languages should always have new variables initalised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is containing uninitialized memory. Your `strcat` is searching for the first `0` byte, and there is no guarantee where it is, or if there even is any (in which case `strcat` would even search after the allocated memory, probably incarnating the invoked UB as a crash).

Set the first byte to `0` when using `strcat`, or better yet, use C++ and use `std::string`.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't initialised your `path` variable. You've allocated memory for it, but it just contains garbage initially, which by chance has a null value. You then concatenate the string, so your path gets appended to the garbage. Replace the first `strcat` with a `strcpy` and you should be right.

Comment: No worries, we've all made that mistake at some point :) I really need to get to bed, but Stack Overflow is addictive!

Answer (score 1):

**Learn to use a debugger**  (like `gdb` on Linux) and ask for all warnings from your compiler (like `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux).

You allocated but did not fill your array. Try perhaps

```
 size_t targetfilenamelen = strlen(args->targetFileName);
 size_t targetfilepathlen = strlen(args->targetFilePath);
 char* path = new char[targetfilenamelen+targetfilepathlen+1]; // extra zero byte
 strcpy (path, args->targetFileName);
 strcat (path, args->targetFilePath);
```

Better yet, use `std::string` e.g.

```
 std::string name(args->targetFileName);
 std::string path(args->targetFilePath);
 std::string res = name+path;
```