# newbie c++; adding char* arrays?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, strcat

Currently in the process of learning c++ and maybe it's because I am *really* frustrated right now but I really can't seem to wrap my simple little head around this:

There's a class constructor:

```
Class (const char* file);
```

I use it like this in my main class:

```
char* chararr = new char[2048]; 
//stuff with charrarr
// std::cout << chararr would be: "C:\stuff\paths\etc\"
Class c( strcat(chararr , "filename.file"));
//I want it to be: "C:\stuff\paths\etc\filename.file
Class c2( strcat(chararr , "filename2.file2"));
////I want this to be: "C:\stuff\paths\etc\filename2.file2" but it is instead
// "C:\stuff\paths\etc\filename.filefilename2.file"
```

The problem is that strcat modifies the chararr so the second time I do this, with Class c2, it gets all messed up... I'm guessing it's a very very basic thing to do and it gets me even more frustrated knowing I'm missing something really obvious...

Comment: Are you aware that you can simply say `Class c("filename.file");`?

Comment: You need a copy constructor which deep copies the `char *`

Comment: You are also strcating an uninitialized array - look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311942/c-i-have-allocated-a-char-array-and-the-content-is-b

Comment: If you are using MS Visual C++, then click on a function name (e.g. strcat) and press F1 for help, including related functions. If you are using Linux, http://www.cplusplus.com/, http://linux.die.net/man/, etc

Comment: If you are writing Class, consider modifying it to accept a std::string instead of const char*, to avoid managing the memory yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error in you code first time you should call `strcpy()`, whereas you are concatenates with garbage.

```
Class c( strcpy(chararr , "filename.file"));
```

else it concatenate with garbage, undefined behavior.

Edit:

```
// std::cout << chararr would be: "C:\stuff\paths\etc\"
size_t len = strlen(chararr);  // <--- notice
Class c( strcat(chararr , "filename.file"));
// path\path2\filename.file
//            ^ replace `f` with '\0'          
chararr[len] = '\0'; // <--- notice
Class c2( strcat(chararr , "filename2.file2"));
```

Comment: Why not simply `Class c("filename.file")`? What will `strcpy()` be good for here?

Comment: @g-makulik I just in inform him mistake

Comment: I think I explained this incorrectly, charrarr isn't an empty array. It's an char* array like this: "path\path2\" so c would be: path\path2\filename.file" and c2 would be "path\path2\filename2.file", I've edited the original post with a more detailed explanation

Comment: @optional then 2nd will be `"path\path2\filename.filefilename2.file"`

Comment: Yes, that was my problem! :(

Comment: @optional let me know if its still buggy

Comment: Thanks! Will choose this as my correct answer, reason: g-makulik has +1'd it and while Neil Kirks solution appears to be working as well, I feel as if this one is more in line with the question (which only uses chars and no strings)!

Comment: @optional Thanks a lots to appreciate, and  @ g-makulik Double Thanks to support me to win :) :) I first time got this much repo in a day @ SO thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using `strcat` when you don't need (as it seems) to concatenate strings? You could simply do:

```
class Class {
public:
    Class(const char* file) {}
    // ...
};

int main() {
    Class c("filename.file");
    Class c2("filename2.file2");
}
```

or, if you really need to concatenate strings use `std::string` instead of `const char*`.

Answer (score 3):

std::string is easier to manipulate, grows in size automatically and deletes itself automatically. The only gotcha in this case, is that the class must make its own copy of the text you pass as the pointer, because when the string changes data or goes out of scope, the pointer is no longer valid.

```
std::string mystr = "filename.file";
MyClass c(mystr.c_str());
mystr = "filename2"; // reset string
mystr += ".file2" // concatenate
MyClass c2(mystr.c_str());
```

If you wrote the class, change it to use std::string as well.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(const std::string& str_in)
        : str(str_in) // initialization list
    {
    }

    std::string str;
};

std::string mystr = "filename.file";
MyClass c(mystr);
mystr = "filename2"; // reset string
mystr += ".file2" // concatenate
MyClass c2(mystr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to reinitialize `chararr` if you want to use it this way:

```
char* chararr = new char[2048]; 

strcpy(chararr,"path\\path2\\");
Class c( strcat(chararr , "filename.file"));
strcpy(chararr,"path\\path2\\");
Class c2( strcat(chararr , "filename2.file2"));
```

For that you're using c++ I'd recommend using `std::string` anyway.